# Клиент-Сервер(Go).Некоректно отображает полученные данные

Tags: golang, gameserver

Клиент отправлает пакет

```
00 55 80 00 00 00 01 AF 00 07 6E 6F 62 69 6C 6C    .U........nobill
00 00 0A 4C 6F 67 69 6E 55 73 65 72 00 00 18 FA    ...LoginUser....
2E 53 24 63 2C 4B D2 54 B7 3E E9 B7 35 BE E2 A4    .S$c,K.T.>..5...
D3 E1 56 1A 75 C0 E1 00 18 30 30 2D 46 46 2D 43    ..V.u....00-FF-C
37 2D 43 45 2D 46 32 2D 46 32 2D 30 30 2D 30 30    7-CE-F2-F2-00-00
00 03 8F 00 88
```

---

```
...
      func main(){
      listen, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:1973")
        client, _ := listen.Accept()
        var (
            buf     *bytes.Buffer = bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})
            tempBuf []byte        = make([]byte, 2048)
        )
        for {
            ln, _ := client.Read(tempBuf)
            buf.Write(tempBuf[:ln])
                if buf.Len() == 2 {
                fmt.Print(buf.Bytes())
                }
       }
    }
```

Вывод `[0 2]`

Разбираюсь в коде [github](https://github.com/Nyarum/noterius/blob/master/core/buffers.go)

Comment: Выглядит нормально, хоть и не нужен здесь `bytes.Buffer`. Код клиента есть? Как он посылает данные: простой записью байт в сокет или как-то сериализует?

Comment: '00 55 80 00 00 00 01 AF 00 07 6E 6F 62 69 6C 6C .U........nobill 00 00 0A 4C 6F 67 69 6E 55 73 65 72 00 00 18 FA ...LoginUser.... 2E 53 24 63 2C 4B D2 54 B7 3E E9 B7 35 BE E2 A4 .S$c,K.T.>..5... D3 E1 56 1A 75 C0 E1 00 18 30 30 2D 46 46 2D 43 ..V.u....00-FF-C 37 2D 43 45 2D 46 32 2D 46 32 2D 30 30 2D 30 30 7-CE-F2-F2-00-00 00 03 8F 00 88'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Оказывается, игровой клиент должен получить пакет с датой, после чего он отправляет пакет авторизации.